Finding possible values of $\frac{a+b+c}{a-b-c}$
Let $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}$ be  triples  satisfying
$a(a-9)-(b+c)(b+c+1) = 19$
Which of the following is NOT a possible value of (more than one correct option may exist)
$$\frac{a+b+c}{a-b-c}$$
A) $\frac{13}{5}$
B) $\frac{43}{6}$
C) $\frac{17}{8}$
D) $\frac{19}{7}$
This question appeared in my exam, and unfortunately, I couldn't solve it within the allotted time due to its difficulty. It seems quite challenging, and I initially thought it might be tackled by fully factorizing the given expression. However, when I attempted to expand the brackets, it became overwhelmingly convoluted. I'm uncertain how to proceed with this problem nothing is coming in my mind even now. I would greatly appreciate any insights or hints that could guide me toward the correct approach.

As a first step, I suggest letting $~d = (b + c).$

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

You have wasted a lot of our time with your carelessness! Please try to get it right next time.

The Given equation represents a rectangular Hyperbola in cartesian plane, if letting $x = a$ and $y = b + c$, the desired values are the points of intersection of the hyperbola $$(x-\frac{9}{2})^2-(y+\frac 12)^2=39$$ with the line $$ l : \frac{x + y}{x - y} = s$$ where $s$ is arbitrary.
The slope of the asymptotes to the hyperbola are $\{-1,1\}$ and hence, In order to have a real solution the slope of the line $$ l : \frac{y}{x} = \frac{s-1}{s+1}$$ must be bounded inside $(-1,1)$.
The possible values of $s$ shall be the ones which satisfy the inequality
$$-1 \lt \frac{s-1}{s+1} \lt 1$$
Solving the above Inequation
$$s \in (0,\infty)$$
Hence $s$ accepts all positive values and so does $\frac{a+b+c}{a-b-c}$

That is a very neat presentation! The idea of intersecting with lines makes this the best answer yet imo.

From @Vasili's answer,
the equation
$$a^2-9a-d^2-d=19\\\implies \bigg(a-\frac{9}{2}\bigg)^2-\bigg(d+\frac 12\bigg)^2=39$$
We can replace $a-4.5=\sqrt{39}\sec t$ and $d+0.5=\sqrt{39}\tan t$.
So $$\frac{a+d}{a-d}=\frac{\sqrt{39}(\sec t+\tan t)+4}{\sqrt{39}(\sec t-\tan t)+5}=f(t)$$
This function is discontinuous at $t=\frac{4n+1}{2} π$ where it goes upto $\infty$ but continuous elsewhere.Also it has a period of $2π$.
Roots are $t= 2 π n + 2\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{23} (-55 - 8 \sqrt{39}))) n\in \mathbb{Z}$ which is a real value. From this, we can conclude that this function has valid values from $(0,\infty)$. Thus, all given options are possible outcomes.

First, note that $b$ and $c$ are never used separately, so define $d = b + c$ as @user266192 suggested.
$$a(a-9)-d(d+1) = 19$$
$$a^2-9a-(d^2+d) = 19$$
Let's complete the squares:
$$(a^2-9a+\frac{81}{4}) - (d^2 + d + \frac{1}{4}) = 19 + \frac{81}{4} - \frac{1}{4}$$
$$(a-\frac{9}{2})^2 - (d + \frac{1}{2})^2 = 39$$
This is the equation of a hyperbola of “radius” $\sqrt{39}$ centered at $(a = \frac{9}{2}$, $d = - \frac{1}{2}$).  So we can write $a$ and $d$ in parametric form as:
$$a = \frac{9}{2} + \sqrt{39}\cosh(t)$$
$$d = -\frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{39}\sinh(t)$$
Let $y = \frac{a + d}{a - d}$ be one of the answer choices.  Then:
$$y = \frac{4 + \sqrt{39}\cosh(t) + \sqrt{39}\sinh(t)}{5 + \sqrt{39}\cosh(t) - \sqrt{39}\sinh(t)} = \frac{4 + \sqrt{39}e^{t}}{5 + \sqrt{39}e^{-t}}$$
Solving for $t$ gives:
$$t = \ln\left(\frac{5y - 4 \pm \sqrt{25y^2 + 116y + 16}}{2\sqrt{39}}\right)$$
Now, let's plug in each of the answer choices:
Choice A: $y = \frac{13}{5}$
$$t \approx 0.9109609965871138$$
$$a \approx 13.52042714904326$$
$$d \approx 6.009078732908115$$
Choice B: $y = \frac{43}{6}$
$$t \approx 1.8317808230648231$$
$$a \approx 24.5$$
$$d \approx 18.5$$
Choice C: $y = \frac{17}{8}$
$$t \approx 0.7331685343967135$$
$$a \approx 12.5$$
$$d \approx 4.5$$
Choice D: $y = \frac{19}{7}$
$$t \approx 0.9490841587774661$$
$$a \approx 13.775189753873146$$
$$d \approx 6.357779886402991$$
All four choices satisfy both $a^2-9a-(d^2+d)=19$ and $y = \frac{a + d}{a - d}$.
